# libreoffice set as default but files still opened using WPS office

Tags: 18.04, default-programs

I'm on 18.04 and my `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` reads:

```
application/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop
...
text/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

But still when I double-click a csv file, it is opened using WPS office. I already restarted my machine so it can't be a cache thing.
How is this possible and how do I get libreoffice to be the default for csv (and other) files?
It seems that WPS office somehow overwrites the default applications behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the .csv file and see what it set as the default application to open with - presumably it will be WPS.

Select Open with Other Application and if it lists LibreOffice Calc as Recommended application, select it from there after which the default will be set for the future.

If not in the list of recommended than click on View All Applications and select LibreOffice Calc from there.

[image]

Comment: Libreoffice is listed under Recommended Applications, WPS is not, but still when I open it that way with Libreoffice and then re-try double-clicking, it opens using WPS.